# How can I extract a list of years with django queryset in an optimised way?

Tags: python, django

I want to get a list of years from `MyModel` instances date attribute.

This is the way I do this now:

```
dates = MyModel.objects.filter(site=site).dates('date', 'year')
years = [date.year for date in dates]
```

The result looks like:

```
dates = [datetime.date(2004, 2, 1), datetime.date(2005, 3, 1)]
years = [2004, 2005]
```

Is there any simpler way do this? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Seems perfectly simple to me.

Comment: @Daniel I just wonder if I can do it in even more simple way, one line or something. If my current code is good, I will not change it :)

Answer (score 2):

For Django 1.10 and higher you can use [ExtractYear](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.datetime.ExtractYear). You could get the list of years by doing this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractYear
dates = MyModel.objects.filter(site=site)\
                       .annotate(year=ExtractYear('date'))\
                       .values('year')
```

Note that unlike your solution this does not return a distinct list of years. If you want a distinct list, you should add a call to `distinct()` in the chain.

It's useful if you want to have the year as part of other data in a queryset, or if you want to count how often each year happens.

If you just want the distinct list of years, your solution is just as good.

Comment: I am using Django 1.9 in this project, but it's always good to know there is something like this in higher version  :) Thank you.

Comment: Somehow the distinct call does not make the list distinct on year. I will also resort to python, but was hoping there was a faster/database way to do it for 100+ MyModel instances.

Answer (score 0):

years = list(MyModel.objects.values_list("date__year"))

Comment: Hello Olivia! Looks like you are new to StackOverflow. When posting an answer, please provide some context and explanation and not just the code snippet.